# Reducing the infinite language problem to halting problem

Tags: computability, reductions, undecidability, halting-problem

Let: $INF = \{ w \in \Sigma^* | \quad |L(M_w)| = \infty \} $.

It is easy to show with Rices theorem that $INF$ is not decidable.
($INF$ is non-trivial because of $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$).

How can you show this with a reduction onto the halting problem (for example)?

---

**Here are my thoughts:**

I had an idea of running the decider of $INF$ in its own input, but couldnt get very far.

Another idea that I just had was:

Construct a Turing machine TM M' that halts if the language is finite, and loops endlessly if it is infinite:

```
M'(w):
for i=0,1,...
    simulate M_w on w_i
```

Knowing the halting problem we cannot know if that turing machine will halt or not. We have supposedly reduced $HALT$ on $INF$. Is this correct ? (Since we take an instance of $HALT$

Can I get some feedback on my solutions ?

Comment: To show that INF is undecidable, you want to reduce HALT to INF, not the other way around.

Comment: Moreover, you *cannot* reduce INF to HALT, since HALT is in $\Sigma_1^0$ whereas INF is $\Pi_2^0$-complete.

Comment: ok that makes sense to me, thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your language is actually [$\Pi_2^0$-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy), and in particular even harder than the halting problem.

We can show that $\mathrm{INF}$ is $\Pi_2^0$-hard by reduction from $\mathrm{TOT} = \{ w : L(M_w) = \Sigma^* \}$. Indeed, given a Turing machine $M$, we can construct a Turing machine $M'$ which on input $x$, simulates $M$ sequentially on all inputs $y \leq x$ (using lexicographic order). It is not hard to check that $M'$ halts on infinitely many inputs iff $M$ halts on *all* inputs.

To show that $\mathrm{INF}$ is in $\Pi_2^0$, notice that a machine $M$ halts on infinitely many inputs if and only if for all inputs $x$ there exists an input $y \geq x$ and a number $n$ such that $M$ halts on $y$ within $n$ steps. Since the last condition is decidable, it follows that $\mathrm{INF}$ is in $\Pi_2^0$.

To answer the question you are interested in, all you need to do is to find a reduction from the halting problem to $\mathrm{TOT}$.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I have two questions:
$\Pi^0_2$ means "all total functions described by turing-machines" ?
and: also my approach (if only sketched out) with rice is not _wrong_ is it ?

Comment: The class $\Pi_2^0$ is explained in the Wikipedia article on the arithmetical hierarchy.